# Generating reachability matrix from a given adjacency matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

What is the best algorithm for generating a reachability matrix from a given adjacency matrix. There is warshall's algorithm but it is not the best method. There are some other methods but the procedures are more theoretical. Is there any module or with which I can create a reachability matrix with ease. I am working on python 2.7.

Comment: Directed or undirected graph? Why is Floyd-Warshall's algorithm "not the best"? There are undoubtedly many implementations out there, but some more details of your graphs would be helpful..

Comment: Why not a simple BFS or DFS.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The entries in the nth power of adjacency matrix count the number of walks of length n between the vertices. This in general may not converge.

Comment: @gilleain I have  a KxK matrix where K>=10000. For such a matrix the number of vertices  is minimum 10000. The time complexity of warshall's algorithm is O(V^3). Therefore it is not a good algorithm for such adjacency matrix. The graph is a digraph containing cycles. Its not necessarily always a connected graph.

Comment: @user1990169: You're right, and I've now deleted that comment.  I should have written "Keep computing A = saturateAtOne(A^2 + A) until the resulting matrix doesn't change any more, where saturateAtOne(X) changes any matrix entry in X that is over 1 to 1".  But *each step* takes O(n^3) time (or possibly a fraction less if you use a fancy matrix multiplication algorithm) and that needs to be multiplied by O(log(diameter)) steps, so F-W should be faster anyway -- and of course DFS/BFS blows F-W away!

Comment: http://www.cs.hut.fi/~enu/thesis.html

Comment: This question violates several SO guidelines: it is opinion-based, it makes unsubstantiated (and doubtful) assertions and it asks for an external resource recommendation.  It should be closed, but of course, we cannot close a question with a bounty on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do it faster than O(n³) in general case for directed graph.

That being said, you can try to use clever technics to reduce the constant.

For example, you can do the following:

1. Convert your graph into [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) by finding all [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) and replacing them with a single vertex. This can be done in Θ(V + E) or Θ(V²)
2. On the new graph, run DFS to calculate reachability for all vertices, but, when updating reachability set for a vertex, do it in the fast vectorized way. This is technically Θ( (V + E) * V ) or Θ(V³), but the constant will be low (see below).

The proposed vectorized way is to have the reachability set for every vertex represented as the bit vector, residing on GPU. This way, the calculation of the union of two sets is performed in extremely fast parallelized manner on GPU. You can use any tensor library for GPU, for example, [tf.bitwise](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bitwise/bitwise_or).

After you calculated reachability bit vectors for every vertex on GPU, you can extract them into CPU memory in Θ(V²) time.